# 2d array for 2d function from 2 1d arrays (Python)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make a 2D 5850x5850 array from two 1D arrays by putting them into this equation for a 2D gausian.

```
psf  = 1/(2*np.pi*sigma_x*sigma_y) * np.exp(-(x**2/(2*sigma_x**2) + y**2/(2*sigma_y**2)))
```

However it gives back a 1D array, waht am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you explain in words what this expression is supposed to do, and maybe add an example? Because, trying to understand what you want from the expression will not work, since the expression is wrong (as you say).

Comment: Are `x` and `y` your 1d arrays?  Your equation just does element by element math on those 2.  There's nothing there that says 'do some sort of outer or cross computation'.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly:
All you need to do is to alter shape of your arrays.
E.g.

```
x.shape=(5850,1) # now it is column array
y.shape=(1,5850) # now it is row array
```

Then you can proceed as in your original post. The result will be 5850 by 5850 array. Each row will correspond to different x and each column will correspond to different y.

However I would change few things in your code to make it look like that:

```
psf  = 1/(2*np.pi*sigma_x*sigma_y) * np.exp(-(x*x/(2*sigma_x*sigma_x) + y*y/(2*sigma_y*sigma_y)))
```

Squaring values is usually inefficient (unless your complier translates it to multiplication, but in Python there is no complier to rely on). Squaring is much slower than multiplication. When you take a value to the power your computer needs to be ready that it might be negative or that it is not an integer. There is no such overhead when you multiply values.

Try:

```
for i in xrange(0,1000000):
    z=i**2

for i in xrange(0,1000000):
    z=i*i
```

Formar ran 0.975s on my machine whereas later only 0.267s.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't understand that x and y are to mean that for every x, you must do this for each y.  If you can't find a library to create 2d functions/guassians more conveniently, try:

```
z =  np.empty((len(x), len(y))

for idx, yval in enumerate(y):
   z[:,idx] = f(x, yval)
```

Where `f(x, yval)` if you 2d function but where you have `y`, use `yval`.  There's got to be more support for 2d function creation somewhere, maybe try scipy 2d guassian functions in a search?

Answer (score 0):

The proper expression to make a 2d Gaussian would be

```
x = np.arange(0, size, 1, float)
y = x[:,np.newaxis]
x0 = y0 = 0 # your center
np.exp(-4*np.log(2) * ((x-x0)**2 + (y-y0)**2) / radius**2)
```

Comment: This will produce an array of shape x by y?  If so, this is pretty aweomse